# jQuery substr is not affecting selected element

Tags: jquery, substring

So I have a multi line span element that I need to ellipse it if its length is more than a certain number of characters,

I am using jQuery to do so,

```
<div class="myClass">
  <span>a long long text</span>
</div> 

var text = $(".myClass span").text();
if(text.length > 45){
  text.substr(0, 45) + "...";
  console.log("hellooooo");
}
```

they said that this kind of multi-text ellipse can't be done using pure CSS

so the thing is, even though the "helloooo" is printed to the console, the text is not truncated!! what is it that I', doing wrong?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are editing a copy of the text, not the value of the element on the website itself.

You can try something like:

```
var text = $(".myClass span").text();
if(text.length > 45){
  t = text.substr(0, 45) + "...";
  $(".myClass span").text(t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply using `text()` function.

`$(".myClass span").text(text.substr(0, 45) + "...");`

```js
var text = $(".myClass span").text();
if(text.length > 45){
  $(".myClass span").text(text.substr(0, 45) + "...");
  console.log("hellooooo");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass">
  <span>a long long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be preferable to thank good answers with an up vote and the best answer by marking it as accepted.

Comment: I would've loved to, however, up votes still not a possibility for me.. Thanks again Sir :))

Answer (score 0):

You have to realize, that `$(".something").text()` just copies text that is int the element and editing it doesn't change the original text.

Also `text.substr` creates new string rather than altering what already is in the `text` variable.

You need to update it manually with

```
 $(".myClass span").text(text.substr(0, 45) + "...");
```

Comment: yup, I totally missed on that. Thanks ;))